# curve3d can't find local function "fn"

Tags: r, scoping

I'm trying to use the `curve3d` function in the `emdbook`-package to create a contour plot of a function defined locally inside another function as shown in the following minimal example:

```
library(emdbook)
testcurve3d <- function(a) {
  fn <- function(x,y) {
    x*y*a
  }
  curve3d(fn(x,y))
}
```

Unexpectedly, this generates the error

```
> testcurve3d(2)
 Error in fn(x, y) : could not find function "fn"
```

whereas the same idea works fine with the more basic `curve` function of the `base`-package:

```
testcurve <- function(a) {
  fn <- function(x) {
    x*a
  }
  curve(a*x)
}
testcurve(2)
```

The question is how `curve3d` can be rewritten such that it behaves as expected.

Comment: Oddly, it "works" if `fn <- function(x,y)` is replaced by `fn <<- function(x,y)`, showing that the problem is the environment in which `curve3d` is evaluating the expression.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is my temporary and not so nice fix for the problem at the moment.

Comment: I'm sure @BenBolker will have a better solution though

Comment: I think I don't, actually, other than digging in to the evaluation environment and seeing if there's a better way to do this.   Sorry ... I could write an answer explaining the problem, but at the moment I don't have an obvious solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can temporarily `attach` the function environment to the search path to get it to work:

```
testcurve3d <- function(a) {
  fn <- function(x,y) {
    x*y*a
  }
  e <- environment()
  attach(e)
  curve3d(fn(x,y))
  detach(e)
}
```

**Analysis**

The problem comes from this line in `curve3d`:

```
eval(expr, envir = env, enclos = parent.frame(2))
```

At this point, we appear to be 10 frames deep, and `fn` is defined in `parent.frame(8)`. So you can edit the line in `curve3d` to use that, but I'm not sure how robust this is. Perhaps `parent.frame(sys.nframe()-2)` might be more robust, but  as `?sys.parent` warns there can be some strange things going on:

> Strictly, sys.parent and parent.frame refer to the context of the
>   parent interpreted function. So internal functions (which may or may
>   not set contexts and so may or may not appear on the call stack) may
>   not be counted, and S3 methods can also do surprising things.
>
> Beware of the effect of lazy evaluation: these two functions look at
>   the call stack at the time they are evaluated, not at the time they
>   are called. Passing calls to them as function arguments is unlikely to
>   be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The eval - parse solution bypasses some worries about variable scope.  This passes the value of both the variable and function directly as opposed to passing the variable or function names.

```
library(emdbook)

testcurve3d <- function(a) {
  fn <- eval(parse(text = paste0(
    "function(x, y) {",
    "x*y*", a,
    "}"
  )))

  eval(parse(text = paste0(
    "curve3d(", deparse(fn)[3], ")"
    )))
}

testcurve3d(2)
```

[image: result]

Comment: This works because you pass to curve3d the `deparse` and that it returns `x*y*a`. The `parse` of `fn` is not necessary, and if you use a more complex function it does not work.

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz - Can back up your claim that this would not work with a complex function by providing an example?

Comment: @BenBolker That's the eval-parse solution for ya!

Comment: Any function with more than one line of code, try this: `fn <- eval(parse(text = paste0("function(x, y) {w <- ", a, "; x*w*y}")))`

Comment: Use escape characters with a newline.  fn <- eval(parse(text = paste0("function(x, y) {\n w <- ", a, "\n x * w * y \n}")))  - SE did not display correctly

Comment: The * sign was not picked up the first time.. try it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180463/discussion-between-juan-antonio-roldan-diaz-and-agriculturist).

Answer (score 1):

I have found other solution that I do not like very much, but maybe it will help you.

You can create the function `fn` how a `call` object and eval this in `curve3d`:

```
fn <- quote((function(x, y) {x*y*a})(x, y))
eval(call("curve3d", fn))
```

Inside of the other function, the continuous problem exists, `a` must be in the global environment, but it is can fix with `substitute`.

**Example:**

```
testcurve3d <- function(a) {
  fn <- substitute((function(x, y) {
                      c <- cos(a*pi*x)
                      s <- sin(a*pi*y/3)
                      return(c + s)
                      })(x, y), list(a = a))
  eval(call("curve3d", fn, zlab = "fn"))
}

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
testcurve3d(2)
testcurve3d(5)
```

[image]